# Multiple field constraints in Elasticsearch fields constraint

Tags: java, elasticsearch

If I have multiple field constraints inside a terms query, will it simply require that there be (at least) one value in common across all of those fields between the query doc and the results? For example:

```
{
    "terms" : {
        "tags" : [ "blue", "pill" ],
        "topics" : [ "Science", "Health" ],
        "minimum_match" : 1
    }
}
```

Does that correspond to "find all documents containing at least (one of the tags "blue" or "pill" or one of the topics "Science" or "Health")"?

As far as I can tell, the TermsQueryBuilder does not allow you add to multiple field constraints.

Comment: May I know if if you had a look at my answer? I just added some more information to it, would you mind letting me know if it was useful?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you are using is not supported. You can only specify a single field and multiple terms that should be found on it.

If you want to search for different terms on different fields, then you should use a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/) and combine different match queries together (you don't need multi_match unless you want to search for the same terms on multiple fields).